# How to synchronize the data between two database?

Tags: vb.net

I've developed an online scheduler that allow my customers to create an appointments with my beauty center. Now I've also a client application with more functions but I can also create appointment as the web application. My goal at this point is synchronize the appointment and the other information such as the settings, customers table, providers table and so on of my client application to the online application. So the step should be this:

1. I create an appointment on my client application
2. The client application insert the appointment in the online database

Now I'm not an expert of synchronization, but I'm actually develop an API that's based simply with an insert statement of the query. The problem's that If I insert the appointment in the online database I've different ID and this is wrong 'cause the id must be the same. So the questions at this point is this:

1.There's a system that allow me to synchronize my data from localhost database to online database?
2. For the ID problem I should create another field like ID_Client or there's something do have the same id as in the client app? If yes I need certainly to check if the ID is already created in the online database and this is quite annoying. I need a simple and power solution for doing this.
What suggest?

Comment: Suggestion: Don't use identity insert on the client.  Add another API call that creates a "blank" appointment on your web database, and returns  the ID.  Insert using the returned ID locally, and update (instead of insert) to the online database.  Not sure if this is the best way.

Comment: Okay but you know systems to synchronize data? Currently what I'm doing is a simple insert query does not seem like a big thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the issue of ID, you should use a GUID for the ID, do not even attempt this with an identity primary key. This allows you to create the ID on the client, web server, etc and they won't duplicate.

For the issue of synchronization, there are different tools and 3rd party applications that will do this for you but I wouldn't suggest doing that with your program because you may have 1000's of clients that would all need complex/expensive synchronization tools. You should write an Web Service that you can send/get changes from and add a DateTime field to your tables so you can tell which database has the latest data when the record already exists.  It takes a little work but this is how I would do it.

BTW, if you are using VS2015 and your clients are all Windows 10, there are some build in features for building apps that synchronize for you. But it will be a while before we can expect users to have Windows 10.

Comment: There is a tutorial that explain the GUIDs technique?

Comment: A GUID is a Globally Unique Identifier. It is generated by using information from your network card and date/time and some other random information to try to make an ID that is unique in the whole world. As you can imagine, it is NOT guaranteed unique but I don't think anyone has ever run into an issue but it is possible if you were running something with a quantum processor maybe. Asking for a tutorial on a GUID is like asking for a tutorial on the STRING data type. GUID is a data type, not a web service or anything fancy like that. Google it for more info.

Comment: At this point I can use the hash of each record that's I guess is a GUID I think.

Comment: No, it isn't and that is FAR from unique. In VB, you would use `Guid.NewGuid` to generate a new GUID. Most databases have the ability to do it to, you'll have to research how to do it for your database and how to store it depending on your database.

Comment: Thank you Steve but I noticed that I can use the hash that's the same in the two database.